# what does this do? printf '\t%s\n' "$@"

Tags: shell-script, printf, case-sensitivity

I'm writing a larger bash script, and I've found this snippet to test if a directory exists **case insensitive**

Now, if I now have one directory called subs this script will print the path, and if I have two (or more) it will print those too..

but I don't really understand how, since there is only 1 print function, and no loop?

I guess it has something to do with the ***'\t%s\n' "$@"*** code...
someone that can explain this to me? (trying to understand)

```
dir=~/test1
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
set -- $dir/[s]ubs/
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo 'There is at least one directory called "subs" (case ignored):'
    printf '\t%s\n' "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell printf uses the format as many times as it has args for. So it has a built-in loop.

If it had three % strings in the string, it would use three args at a time.  The last time round, it will default one or two args to blank/zero if it needs to.

The "$@" expands all the $1, $2, ... current args to separate quoted strings.

In the print format (the first argument)

\t (escaped t) is a tab and will indent by 8 spaces.

%s takes the next unused arg and inserts it as a string.

\n (escaped n) is a newline and will make the next line start below and in column.

`man bash` is a command that shows you all built-in commands, including a couple of pages about printf.

`man -s 1 printf` is a command that shows you what the external command /bin/printf does. It is very similar to (but not identical to) the bash built-in, but a lot easier to find.

Comment: but what does \t%s\n "$@"  mean?  \n = new line,

Comment: @alecxs I expanded my answer after JoBe's comment and before yours: my original was only the first 3 lines. The OP's profile is helpful.